# Random number game in python, with according messages

Tags: python, random, while-loop, dice

I am trying to make a random-number game, where you have to guess which random number Python gets from 1-10. And also do so that if you write e.g. 11, 104 etc. it will ask you to try again to write a valid input.

This is what I have tried so far, but I cant seem to figure out what I have done wrong. All help is greatly appreciated:)
Sorry if it is an easy question, I am still fairly new to Python

```
while True:
    try:
        number_in = int(input("Please insert a number between 1-10: "))
    except ValueError:
            print("Sorry. Try again to insert a number from 1 to 10")
            continue
            
if 1 < number <10:
    print("Your input was invalid. Please insert a number from 1 to 6")
    continue
else:
    break

game_1 = randint(1,10)

if number_in == game_1:
    print(f"The result was {game_1}. Your guess was correct, congratulations!")
else:
    print(f"The result was {game_1}. Your guess was NOT correct. Try again")
```

Comment: What do you expect to happen and what happens instead?

Comment: You have to `break` out of your infinite loop after `number_in = ...`. As a side note, `continue` in the `except` block is useless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of small mistakes, here is a working solution. I'll try to talk you through it:

```
import random

while True:
    try:
        number_in = int(input("Please insert a number between 1-10: "))
        if 1 <= number_in <= 10:
            break
        else:
            print("Your input was invalid. Please insert a number from 1 to 10")
    except ValueError:
        print("Sorry. Try again to insert a number from 1 to 10")

game_1 = random.randint(1, 10)

if number_in == game_1:
    print(f"The result was {game_1}. Your guess was correct, congratulations!")
else:
    print(f"The result was {game_1}. Your guess was NOT correct. Try again")
```

1. You need to break from the loop when a correct input is met
2. Continue within the `except` block is redundant - it will continue to the next iteration nevertheless
3. `break` and `continue` are keywords used only inside a loop
4. Conditional should be inside the loop
5. Conditional has wrong variable name (`number_in != number`)
6. Conditional was upside down (number in between 1 and 10 -> "wrong input")
7. Wrong comparison used in conditional. You want to include 1 and 10 as guesses so `<=` instead of `<`
8. `import random` was missing from the example code

Answer (score 1):

1. Please note: continue and break are only used in loop statement.

try this if this is your expected one:

```
from random import randint


def validateNumber():
    valid = False
    if 1 < number_in <10:
        valid = True
        
    return valid

game_1 = randint(1,10)

while True:
    try:
        number_in = int(input("Please insert a number between 1-10: "))
        is_valid = validateNumber()
        if not is_valid:            
            number_in = int(input("Please insert a number between 1-10: "))

        if number_in == game_1:
            print(f"The result was {game_1}. Your guess was correct, congratulations!")
        else:
            print(f"The result was {game_1}. Your guess was NOT correct. Try again")
    except ValueError:            
            break
```